# Explain the infinitude of magnetic flux about a finite length of wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, induction

Ok so it is clear the flux caused by an inductor is limited. If I integrate about a flat spiral inductor I will find that the flux lines going up are a fixed quantity. Since every flux line going up can be mapped to a flux line going down in the outer part of the inductor, I can say that I have found all the flux.

Now suppose I open up the spiral (think of a polar flat spiral) to create a length of straight wire. Logically I should have flux conversion, since flux isn't destroyed or created (magnetic monopole rule). Therefore, I should caclulate an identical flux from a length of wire. However, after doing the calculation similar to the one found here,:http://dev.physicslab.org/Document.aspx?doctype=3&filename=Magnetism_BiotSavartLaw.xml

except for limited values of theta (its a finite length spiral), I find the flux to be infinite! This cannot be right, because an infinte flux for a certain current results in an infinite inductance, crazy as it is. No one would admit a finite wire length should have an infinite inductance, right? The current would never be started because it would take infinite energy!

My calculation can be found here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+b%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29. This is the integral of the B field I found from the Biot-Savart for a limited length of wire.

Bear in mind that the flux is found by taking the integral of the magnetic field by dA, which is dxdy. The integral of dy is just y, or l for length of the spiral (picture the straghtened spiral vertically with increasing r acting as the x axis). Excuse the wordiness of the question but I'm terrible at mathjax or latex, whatever is used.

My goal is for someone to be able to show me how to calculate the flux created by a finite length of wire with a hopefully non-infinite result.

Help would be helpfully appreciated.

Comment: A finite length of wire is not a realizable physical system. The current always has to return somewhere, which will give you a field component, which will offset the flux at infinity, but does not have to change the field close to the wire significantly. Therefor the finite wire segment is only a good approximation for the field that is close (enough) to it. One should not expect the integration all the way out to infinity to produce a physical result, though, since the system itself is unphysical.